# swab in Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm porting C++ code to Android that references _swab.
While there are related header files in Android NDK r15c (swab.h, swab.h), none provides a signature for swab() or _swab().

What is a good workaround?

Comment: What does that function do?

Comment: There's a [swab()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/swab.3.html) (no leading underscore, so dunno if it does what you want) in normal Linux+glibc, dunno about Android.

Comment: @Shawn Google decided to not add swab() to Android NDK. Why is unclear. Related discussion here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36925339

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Android does have it, but not until android-28: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/1eb5976d7505f299754040e19792a0de94abccbc/libc/include/unistd.h#318

Here's a change to add an inline for backporting to old releases: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/bionic/+/984334. Not merged into any NDK yet. Until it is, you can paste that function into your code to get moving. Once that ships and you've upgraded to an NDK that contains it you can delete it again.

Comment: Was this change supposed to go into the new NDK? I'm still getting compiler errors on `swab` with the latest tools and plugins as of Dec 11 2019.

Comment: The change never made it past presubmit and I had some other things come up that took my time. I'll try to find some time to revisit it.

Comment: Whatever happened with this?  I've been rolling a custom version for years which I have a feeling is not ideal.  Would love to drop my hack.

Comment: Same as my last update, unfortunately. I just put it at (nearly) the top of my todo list whether it belongs there or not though, so presumably r22. Updated the answer to at least not be misleading about r21.

Comment: Figured out what was wrong and got it submitted. We'll pick it up for r22.